# Как автоматически установить роль для авторизованного пользователя в Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, role, auto

У меня есть регистрация на сайте, но роль пользователя устанавливается только через базу.
Как автоматически назначить роль авторизованному пользователю?

Таблица Role

```
package com.example.playGame.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Set;
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Таблица User

```
package com.example.playGame.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Контролер регистрации

```
@Controller
public class registrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user",new User());
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/process_register")
    public String processRegister(User user, Role role) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "register_success";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог решить сам

Таблица Role

```
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;

public Role(){

}
public Role(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
public Role(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
public Role(String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
public void addRole(Role role){
    this.roles.add(role);
}
```

Таблица User

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String email;
private String password;

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

public void addRole(Role role) {
    this.roles.add(role);
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Контролер регистрации

```
@GetMapping("/registration")
public String registration(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user",new User());
    return "registration";
}

@PostMapping("/process_register")
public String processRegister(User user) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
    Role roleUser = roleRepository.findByName("USER");
    user.addRole(roleUser);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "register_success";
}
```